# Can't make Yasnippets work in Emacs, help!

Tags: emacs, code-snippets

I can't make Yasnippets work (normal version).
When I start Emacs it says:

```
error: Error ~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c/snippets/ not a directory
```

I added this to my .emacs file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
    "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c")
    (require 'yasnippet) ;; not yasnippet-bundle
    (yas/initialize)
    (yas/load-directory "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c/snippets/")
```

and my yasnippets files are placed in the following folders:

```
D:\Program Files\emacs-23.1\site-lisp\plugins\yasnippet-0.6.1c
```

and the snippets:

```
D:\Program Files\emacs-23.1\site-lisp\plugins\yasnippet-0.6.1c\snippets
```

All others plugins work so I'm sure its the right load-path

Help!

Comment: For this to work, you need to take care of two things.  First, there is an ".emacs.d" directory mentioned in .emacs, but real paths do not contain such directory. Second, it assumes that environment variable HOME should be set to D:\Program Files\emacs-23.1, which is possible, but not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could write the whole path, instead of a relative one, like this:

```
add-to-list 'load-path
    "D:/Program Files/emacs-23.1/site-lisp/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c")
    (require 'yasnippet) ;; not yasnippet-bundle
    (yas/initialize)
    (yas/load-directory "D:/Program Files/emacs-23.1/site-lisp/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c/snippets")
```

Notice the forward slashes, and please make sure that emacs doesn't mind the spaces... Windows is less forgiving than Linux with these kinds of paths. Also, make sure your emacs install reads that dir. Usually, you should put an emacs dir where your .emacs is (in Windows), that makes it more clear. It

Another thing: 1) maybe you're trying your snippet in the wrong mode. Make sure there is a snippet for the mode you're in.

See here as well, lots of info here: [GNU Emacs for Windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/big.html)